# read in .csv files into a list using a character vector for filenames

Tags: r, list, csv, lapply, readr

I'm reading in a list of `.csv` files but they're coming in with a single column when in actuality the `.csv` files have many columns.  How can I specify the delimiter is `","` when using an `lapply` function?

`files`: the character value vector containing filepath names

```
# produces a list of dfs with only one column
data <- lapply(files, read.delim)

# Next I tried a readr application but that gives me the error
df <- readr::read_delim(files,delim = ",")

Error: Files must all have 57 columns:                                                                                              
    * File 2 has 59 columns
```

Is there a way to read in files to a list with different numbers of columns?

Comment: If you use `lapply`, use `data <- lapply(files, read.delim, sep=",")` (`read.delim` does not have a `delim=` parameter, it uses `sep=`) or if it's just comma separated values, just use `data <- lapply(files, read.csv)`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution similar to the previous one (without using for cycle) is:

```
setwd ("/yourpath/") 
file_list <- list.files()
dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(file_list,
                                  FUN=function(files){read.csv2(files, header=TRUE)}))
```